# Saving file to specific local directory or folder using jspdf

Tags: jspdf, filesaver.js

I am using Filesave.js to save file generated from JSPDF library, and want to save it to a specific folder like C:\PDF\Test.pdf

I am using below code but it is not working.

```
var filename = "C:/Test.pdf"
pdf.save(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this.
Check this issue: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/42